# Can't run express server - superCtor is undefined

Tags: node.js, http, express

not sure if anyone can help me beacuse I'm not even sure what causes my problem :\
I wrote small server in express using es6, compiled it using webpack and I'm running it using nodemon. Unfortunately it throws me an error:

[image: error log]

I was looking for some answers but none of them worked for me. Here is my code:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import logger from 'morgan';
import httpProxy from 'http-proxy';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import App from '../client/components/App';
import template from './template';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from '../client/reducers';

var app = express();

const apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target:'http://localhost:3001'
});

app.use('/api', function(req,res){
  apiProxy.web(req,res);
})

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('*', function(req,res){

  const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore);

  const appString = renderToString(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );

  res.send(template({
    body: appString,
    title: 'Hello World from the server'
  }));
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


app.listen(3000);
```

Please ask if you need some more information.

Comment: If this is server code, why are you using webpack?

Comment: Beacause I'm using es6 and importing client files so I could perform server-side rendering

Comment: This seems to be a known node/npm version related issue. Check that you're running the latest version of node and npm and reinstall your packages with the latest version so that you know they're compatible. Sometimes an old dependency from your cache gets into your build and triggers this error.